# unable to mount NFS from command line. Works fine from fstab. works fine if I disable iptables

Tags: ubuntu, nfs

**`Ubuntu 20.04, with IPTables firewall.`**  I explictly allow NFS ports in an out of servers. return (Related or established sessions are permitted)

I have explicity set ports in /etc/sysctl.conf for all servers:
fs.nfs.nlm_udpport=38073

fs.nfs.nlm_tcpport=38747

33333 set in nfs-kernel-server

Ports 111,1110,2949,33333,4045,38073, 38747 are all opened in firewall out and in bound.

**When I try a mount, I get this:**

```
mount.nfs: timeout set for Fri Sep 15 17:25:35 2023
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=192.168.30.150,clientaddr=192.168.10.125'
mount.nfs: mount(2): No such file or directory
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=192.168.30.150'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.30.150 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Unable to send - Operation not permitted
mount.nfs: Operation not permitted
```

However, same mount in FSTAB mounts fine (during reboot)

==== Edit=======

however...  If I flush IPTABLES, it works... with the same "no such" message

```
mount.nfs: timeout set for Sat Sep 16 12:47:04 2023
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 
 vers=4.2,addr=192.168.30.150,clientaddr=192.168.10.125'
mount.nfs: mount(2): No such file or directory
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=192.168.30.150'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.30.150 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: portmap query retrying: RPC: Timed out
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.30.150 prog 100005 vers 3 prot TCP port 33333
```

Comment: Ensure that you have the necessary permissions to mount the NFS share. You may need root or superuser privileges to do this. Try running the mount command with "sudo" if you haven't already. mount.nfs: mount(2): No such file or directory: This error message indicates that the client is unable to find the specified file or directory on the NFS server. It's possible that the path you are trying to mount doesn't exist on the server.Check the NFS server's configuration and permissions to ensure the client has access.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Everyth9ing done with sudo, or as root.
Not sure where the "no such directory is coming from" as it works but has same error message if I flush IPtables.

Comment: I am still having issues...  I am going to pause this for now, and open a separate question.   With your comments (Ace), I can see that I have some other issues.  I have NFS4, but everything is connecting on NFS3.  I think I need to sort that, and possible that fixes this.